# Extremely fast access to an array used by multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, optimization, atomic

I have an array of arrays, each "inner" array/outer array element is 256 bits. I also have multiple threads. All but one thread are non-critical and one of the threads is extremely critical, even performing `compare_exchange_weak()` is considered too expensive.

The critical thread does not need to write to the array, it just needs to read consistent data. The remaining threads all write to the array.

What is the most optimal technique to avoid locks, to allow the critical thread to proceed? Have a second array and then an atomic pointer, alternating between the two "versions"? Is there a name for this technique I can read-up more on?

Comment: do you really need locks to read from shared memory?

Comment: name: double-buffering

Comment: How much data does the critical thread need? 256 bits from one of the elements in a consistent state?

Comment: @101010 If the reads or writes of the element aren't atomic, then yes.

Comment: I don't know of any technique that allows non-atomic, concurrent read/write access to shared data without a locking mechanism of some sort. I'm skeptical that such a technique exists. Even with double buffering you're going to need a mechanism to indicate when the second buffer is valid. If portability isn't a concern, I would look to the OS. For example, on Windows you could use critical sections, which are faster than mutex objects.

Comment: Do the writers edit array elements or only add new ones? Could you use a lock feee ring buffer?

Comment: If you're using two buffers and swap them via an atomic pointer update, you still need synchronization, to avoid the writer stepping on the reader's buffer (the reader must signal the writer when it is done). Something like RCU (possibly hazardpointers, too) would avoid this need.